# Git ignore file for C projects

Tags: c, git

I've just started to learn C (using [Thinking In C](http://mindview.net/CDs/ThinkingInC/beta3)) and I'm wondering about what files I should be ignoring in a C project's git repository.

No suggestion can be too obvious -- I'm a total noob. Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I guess there will be a few generated files that you don't wan't to be sticking in your repo (assuming your build output dir is in your git heirachy):

- object files (.o, o.obj)
- libraries (.lib)
- DLLs, shared objects (.so, .dll)
- Executables (.exe, a.out ?)

GIT ignore files are something I tend to do iteratively.  "Hey, I don't need those things in my repo" ...

Edit: re dmckee's comment

Yep, you definately want to be ignoring swap files, temp files etc.  I have the following as a baseline for my .gitignore:

- *.swp
- *.*~
- thumbs.db

Comment: If you editor makes automatic backups (ala emacs' *~ files), you can probably do without those too.

Comment: Usually you put ignoring of generated files in version controlled and transferred `.gitignore` file (so everybody will have generated files ignored), but ignoring backup files and other types of files depending on your environment (backup files can be *~ or *.bak) in not transferred repository .git/info/exclude (or in core.excludesfile set in ~/.gitconfig).

Answer (score 17):

You can also setup your build to happen in a subdirectory say `build` and then you can ignore the whole thing inside `.gitignore`

> build/

And you're done.

Answer (score 4):

I use this in my .gitignore
But I am building for micro-controllers, so I don't know if it helps you much.

The easiest way to know, is just do a make clean, then add all your files, then do a make all and see what extra stuff appears.

```
#Some of these are related to eclipse. So i keep them out of my repo
.cproject
.dep/
.project
.settings/

#files being edited
*~

# make and build files
*.lst
*.o
*.eep
*.lss
*.map
*.sym

# I keep these, since I prefer having the reference of the final build
# *.elf
# *.hex
```

Answer (score 1):

[Github's `.gitignore` file templates](https://github.com/github/gitignore) cover most of the common files for projects in a variety of languages.

The [C `.gitignore` template](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/C.gitignore) looks like this:

```
# Prerequisites
*.d

# Object files
*.o
*.ko
*.obj
*.elf

# Linker output
*.ilk
*.map
*.exp

# Precompiled Headers
*.gch
*.pch

# Libraries
*.lib
*.a
*.la
*.lo

# Shared objects (inc. Windows DLLs)
*.dll
*.so
*.so.*
*.dylib

# Executables
*.exe
*.out
*.app
*.i*86
*.x86_64
*.hex

# Debug files
*.dSYM/
*.su
*.idb
*.pdb

# Kernel Module Compile Results
*.mod*
*.cmd
.tmp_versions/
modules.order
Module.symvers
Mkfile.old
dkms.conf
```

Comment: Nice! I recommend this as these templates are a result of the collective effort of highly skilled members of the programming community.

Answer (score 0):

Using a ***nix** system and a Makefile, you could add each generated file to `.gitignore`.

As an example I use the following when creating an executable from a single source (Example for a C executable generation):

```
%: %.c
    gcc -o $@ $<
    grep '^$@$$' .gitignore > /dev/null || echo '$@' >> .gitignore
```

The following line can be added to other recipes to add target `$@` to `.gitignore` file:

```
grep '^$@$$' .gitignore > /dev/null || echo '$@' >> .gitignore
```

Explanation:

- `grep '^$@$$' .gitignore` : searches for the target in `.gitignore`

  - `^` indicates start of line
  - `$$` is a single `$` (but Makefile needs `$$` to work) and indicates the end of the line
  - '^$@$$' represents the target name
- `||` : executes the next command only if the left hand one failed

  - so only if `grep ...` does not find the target name in `.gitignore`, `echo ...` is executed
- `echo '$@' >> .gitignore`: adds the target name to `.gitignore`

Eventually, you will add to clean and rebuild everything to make sure all files are correctly ignored