# How to import code into git which is not maintained via a VCS?

Tags: git, version-control, static-libraries

I'm working on a project and want to include a library, which is not available via git, svn, mercurial or any other VCS (just as .tar). How to do this the right way?

Should I create a repo for the code and include it as submodule?

Edit: 
Some further information:

The project is written in C. Maybe there are different ways depending on which language the project is written in?

Comment: You can do whatever you want. What exactly are you trying to ask?

Comment: How to do it correctly? If I have a git repo, I include it as submodule. Any other VCS-repo can included in a similar way. But how to do it when I do not have a repo to include? Just put the source unter ./lib or so? That seems not so portable/maintainable for me!

Comment: "Correctly" is completely arbitrary in this case.  You can include the source directly, you can make your own repo, you can do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just add the files of the library to git?

```
git add <library subdirectory>
git commit -m "added library"
```

The programming language that the library is written in is not really relevant. But you might want to add a `.gitignore` file (to the library folder) that is suited for [ignoring the compilation output of C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846639/git-ignore-file-for-c-projects).

Comment: I thought there would be another way to do it, as updating the lib is not as easy as with submodules (`git foreach submodule update` or so). But if there is no other way how to do it, I have to add the code without repo, I guess!