# GIT Why does object files, Makefiles.mk, *.xml files still show up on unstaged changes even with a nice ignore list

Tags: git, ignore

I am just wondering if there is something wrong with my make file?
Please review the file here. I want to see only source files eg. *.c *.h *.cpp *.hpp. Is it necessary to initialize a GIt (Git init) directory first then create the ignore file and then clone the repository? As you can see I have tried almost everything.

```
# git ls-files --others --exclude-from=.git/info/exclude
# Lines that start with '#' are comments.
# For a project mostly in C, the following would be a good set of
# exclude patterns (uncomment them if you want to use them):

# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/846639/git-ignore-file-for-c-projects

# ignore objects and archives, anywhere in the tree.

#build/
#debug/
#App/
#*.[c]
*.[oa]
*.[o]
*.o
*.[d]
*.[od]
*.d
*.od
*.[lst]
*.[xml]
*.[properties]
*.[bak]
*.o.d
*.elf
*.xml
*.lst
*.bak
*.mk
*.properties

#*.a
#*.d
# ignore files being edited

#*~
#*.lst

# ignore swap files, temp files.
#*.swp
#.~
#thumbs.db
#build/
#*.lst
#*.lss
#*.sys


# ignore generated html files,
#*.html
# except foo.html which is maintained by hand
#!foo.html

# exclude everything except directory foo/bar
#/*
#!/foo
#/foo/*
#!/foo/ba

#### END OF GIT IGNORE LIST ####
```

Comment: I don't see where you ignore makefiles. Also, do they show up as new or modified? If they were _already_ in the repo, ignore list does not apply.

Comment: If those files are already part of the repository, then you would have to `git rm --cached` those files first before `.gitignore` can kick in.  As to whether these files should ever have been committed is another story.

Comment: @ Sergio, They show up as modified.

Comment: @ Tim Biegeleisen. When I first committed->pushed the files in the repository, the *.a, *.mk, *.o files were checked in. Then later I realized that I am just carrying over this extra stuff in my repo and its nuisance because when you are viewing the changes just in GIT it shows your all the line by line comparisons which is bloated comparisons. That's how it ended up there in the first place. So to get them out I created the `gitignore` list and that was not doing the job.

Comment: @ Tim Biegeleisen. There are a lot of files in the object directory. Do all of them individually have to be `git rm --cached <file>`

Answer (score 1):

Associated commands to fix the issue in the opening thread.

1. In your Local repository.

   `git rm --cached *.o //removes the *.object files from local repo`

   `git rm --cached *.mk //removes the *.make files from local repo`

   `git rm --cached *.xml //removes the *.xml files from local repo`

Alternatively, you can simply delete the files from the local working copy and then commit it.

2. Commit your files
3. Push your local to remote

The next time you compile your code and Rescan your changes, those files will not show up in your Unstaged changes. Only the necessary files that you have not excluded in your `info/exclude` will be shown. Clean and Clear.